# Alt-reality film. Being hetero is taboo. People forced to be gay

Tags: story-identification, parallel-universe, alternate-history

This was a really bizarre film. I'm not sure if it was a movie, a mockumentary, or a "what if" alternate reality think piece. The premise was that **straight** people are shunned from society, while being **gay** is the norm. The points I remember are:

- The straight people that want to be accepted in society must go through this "camp" where they're forced to look at gender-specific gay porn, sexual images, and other things, until they renounce their heterosexuality and become homosexual.
- I think certain parts were in black-and-white, while others were in color. I think I remember the scenes talking about "gay is good" being in black and white, and the "straight is bad" scenes being in color. Or vice-versa.
- There was one scene where the focus character was walking with his girlfriend (pre-conversion) through an alley or something and there were all these "hetero" people being sexually depraved out in the open. Grungy-orgy-type stuff.
- I think it ends with the hetero couple from the beginning running into each other with their new homo partners and being all happy and stuff.
- I saw this thing in the late 90's/early 00's in the US. Since I'm not entirely sure if it was all color or all B&W, I can't tell if it looked dated at the time, or if that would have been an intentional art style.
- I have no idea what channel I watched this on, but given the obscurity of it, and it not being an actual porn, I'd guess either HBO, Cinemax, or PBS. Regardless, it was most likely an *After Dark* feature.

Comment: ngl, I read the question title and assumed this was going to be a rant about "forced diversity", until I saw who posted it.

Comment: Too late, but sounds very similar to your description; https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2556936/?ref_=tt_urv

Comment: @F1Krazy What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Valorum Yeah. That's definitely not it.

Comment: I'm sure I read a sci fi short story about forty years ago with a very similar theme, they were brainwashed into being gay, the street mobs claimed you could tell a hetero by the way they walked

Comment: Any chance it was a short film? A lot of them have that kind of plot (as for longer ones, [Almost Normal](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0466669/) is probably be too upbeat and [Love Is All You Need?](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2259122/) is too recent).

Comment: @Walt Yeah, it's not either of those. It could've been a short film I guess. Like I said in the question, I'm not sure what exactly it was.